# .getChildren().add() requires a node and cant add my object

Tags: java, javafx, nodes, gridpane

I made a separate class to setup a grid within JavaFX. The class is as follows:

```
public class Grid { 
    GridPane gp = new GridPane(); //sets grid (10x10)
    gp.setHgap(10);
    gp.setVgap(10);
    gp.setBorder(null);
    gp.setPadding(new Insets(15,15,15,15));

    int[][] shots = new int[10][10];

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(40 , 40);
            gp.add(r, j, i);
        }
    }
}
```

I then have

```
Group root = new Group();
Grid g = new Grid();
root.getChildren().add(g);
```

but it throws the following...

> The method add(Node) in the type List is not applicable for the
>   arguments (Grid)

I understand that `Grid` is not a `Node` type so it can't be added, but I'm really stuck on what I should change to add it. I've tried

```
public class Grid extends GridPane{}
```

Which allows the object to be added in the `Main`, however, it doesn't take the variables added to the *gp* `GridPane` in the other class.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were trying to add an object of a class, which have a node as its data member, into the Group. Instead, you have to add the node itself as a child of the Group.
Try this way :

```
Group root = new Group();
Grid g = new Grid();
root.getChildren().add(g.gp);
```